# How is it possible that the following method uses "syntactic sugar" reserved for constructors?

Tags: class, flutter, oop, dart, constructor

To illustrate my point, the following code contains a method called ColorValueChanger uses this.passedIn as an optional parameter. I thought this was reserved for constructors?

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
 final String passedIn;
 // Value passed in from its host
 ColorValueChanger({Key key, this.passedIn}) : super(key: key);
 _FooState createState() => new _FooState();
}
class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Text(widget.passedIn,);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a constructor.
It sounds more like there is a typo in the example.

The fixed code would be:

```dart
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
 final String passedIn;
 // Value passed in from its host
 Foo({Key key, this.passedIn}) : super(key: key);
 _FooState createState() => new _FooState();
}
class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Text(widget.passedIn,);
 }
}
```